# how to enable ldap filter

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, filter, active-directory, ldap

We have AD import synhronization in SharePoint 2013.

I wrote LDAP filter which works fine on Domain Server. When I insert it LDAP filter I start incremental sync and not workig.

I tried Stop Start UPS service and the same. Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the connection filter in the UPA syc( ADI or FIM). You have to run the **Full sync and followed by couple of sync**.

After full sync it marked the IDs for deleted in Profile Store(you can check those ids in Central admin > manager user profile) and next incremental sync remove it from profile store.